# perfect implementation of database as a service for private cloud

Tags: database, cloud, openstack

I am going to implement database as a service in our private cloud. For this purpose I am looking for an appropriate dbaas implementation. I spent some times with Openstack and their dbaas solution called Trove. But unfortunately it lacks documentation and toturial. So right now I am looking for better solution. So my question would be what is the best opensource solution for dbaas?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I really think Trove is your best option. Everything else will require customization and glue code to get to the level of integration that Trove has with OpenStack. Then you'd have to document your customization and create a tutorial for it.

Did you try this [Add the Database Service](http://docs.openstack.org/icehouse/install-guide/install/apt/content/ch_trove.html) to OpenStack guide?

You can probably also learn a lot by reading through the redstack script found in the [trove-integration](https://github.com/openstack/trove-integration) repo.

If you need help, there are a lot of places to go.

- [OpenStack Mailing List](http://lists.openstack.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/openstack)
- #openstack-trove on IRC (Freenode)
- [ask.openstack.org](https://ask.openstack.org/en/questions/)

Comment: Unfortunately it has a poor documentation for trove project. It seems that trove is a second class product of openstack.